# Am I getting serially downvoted?

Tags: discussion, down-votes

*[Why does frictional force cause a car to move? Also, is friction a reaction force?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/509908/why-does-frictional-force-cause-a-car-to-move-also-is-friction-a-reaction-forc)*

There is the above link for the question to which I answered. I don't find the reason for the answer to be downvoted. Is the answer a low quality answer?

I have been downvoted 5-6 times today. I think it is a case of serial downvoting. I hope that the system and moderators would detect it. I have flagged 5 questions which are pending right now.

I guess that I know the user and I told him that it is the case of serial downvoting which may lead to drastic results, but he didn't stop. Am I really getting targeted?

The links are:

- *https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/510084/230533*
- *https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/510065/230533*
- *https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/506670/230533*
- *https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/506361/230533*
- *https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/488415/230533*
- *https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/509536/230533*
- *[Doesn't the universe violate the law of conservation of linear momentum?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/508641/230533)*

**EDIT**

Thanks to the system and moderators for system check.Today I got the notification of vote reversal.

Comment: It's a single downvote. It's not the end of the world. Leave a polite comment asking for feedback, *listen to the feedback if it does get posted*, and move on.

Comment: Now it's [8 downvotes](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/230533/unique?tab=reputation) today. It looks like serial downvoting.

Comment: @Qmechanic♦ Sir,would you please explain.

Comment: While I don't think serial downvoting is appropriate, from looking over your answers I would say they aren't particularly good. Answers to homework questions in particular should be avoided.

Comment: Some things to note. First, there can only be one down vote per user per post. So the instances where multiple down votes were received on a single post could not have been a user singling you out. Second, some of the questions where your answer has been down voted has answers that have also been down voted. Sometimes users down vote answers on questions they think don't deserve answers. In this case then, you probably were not singled out as well. With that being said, I do agree that there have been a lot of down votes

Comment: All benefit from not [leaving out articles](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Dax90QyXgI&t=17m54s) (no matter the native language).

Comment: Yes, you are under attack. It happens often that my posts get hairsplitting comments, i.e. meaningless complaints about nuances. Best to follow them, because they could have voted you down even without any comment. Give them what they want. Another important thing: 1 upvote negates 5 downs, and a single accept negates 7.5 downs. An accepted post with 3 ups and 5 downs has a score -2, while it is still a +35 rep gain. While voting an answer down, also the downvoter loses 1 rep, and my experience is that these people are very sensitive even for this small losses.

Comment: Another important thing: some downs, particularly the very obviously unfair, unexplained ones, can cause an above average sadness in you. *This is a completely false psychological trap.* Write many good answers, and ignore the downs. Better to think on it, as it is a white noise component in the system. You have a reason to fear only if your multiple posts were deleted by moderation, or if you start to get suspensions due to "low-quality contributions". Or you get an automatic Q/A ban. These are dangerous, induvidual random downs are not. This attack won't last long.

Comment: I downvoted the second bullet point link because it's an answer to a "do my homework for me" query & I don't think we should post answers, even hints, to them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only the person who downvoted knows why they did so. There's no way of knowing their reason unless they choose to reveal it. (Note that technically, even if someone claims to be the downvoter, it is possible they could be lying.)

I don't see anything about your answer that sticks out as a likely reason for it being downvoted. Perhaps someone thought it wasn't clearly explained or that something was factually incorrect about it. I see you got some feedback to that effect in the comments.

Comment: @Unique No, you don't know who has downvoted your answer. The identities of downvoters are not revealed. Please don't claim to know something you don't.

Comment: I bet my claim is true,you are the moderator you can search out.I am ready to leave this website if I would be false

Comment: Sir,its my humble request I got too many downvotes on the main website today.It is really suspicious.Please have a look over it

Comment: @Unique Moderators don't have access to individual votes. However, there is an automated system that detects and reverts serial voting that's targeted at a user rather than at posts; it is documented in [this Meta Stack Exchange thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126829), please read it carefully. As documented there, you should wait to see if the system kicks in; if it doesn't, flag one of the posts for moderator attention ─ they cannot see individual votes, but they *can* see reports of unusual voting activity.

Comment: @Emilio Pisanty I have 5 pending flags.I am sure that he is downvoting because I have some evidence in some comment section of my 3-4 posts

Comment: @David Z Sir,Please have a look over my reputation history so far today .https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/230533/unique?tab=reputation

Comment: @Unique As I said, please don't claim to know who voted on your answer. It's inappropriate behavior on this site. Nothing in your reputation history changes that.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as user David Z said, voting identity is kept private. Only the user who has voted does know the reason.

Moreover as users downvote an answer, each vote costs the down-voter $1$ reputation point so that they don't do that just for fun or revenge. We should really down-vote only when the answer is very unclear or incorrect or both and mention the reason so that the answer-er learns where (he/ she) has gone wrong.

Comment: Instead, "just for fun" and revenge downs are coming to questions.

Answer (score 2):

I have seen that many of your  answer either homework type, or similar to this, which should be avoided, secondly if someone has down voted your answer, ask gently the reason for down voting, it not improves question quality, but their also increase the knowledge. I think you are not serially down voted.